# Django order_by() not doing proper ordering

Tags: python, django, django-custom-tags

I have the following query set on Django in 2 places the only thing is the limitation and gives me different results

Here is the first result for the following QuerySet

```
list_empleados = empleado.objects.filter(
    empresa=session_empresa
).order_by('-puntos')[:3]
```

[image]

The proper result should be:

19,13,9 instead of 9,19,13 see what i mean?

Here is the second QuerySet

```
list_empleados = empleado.objects.filter(
    empresa=session_empresa
).order_by('puntos')
```

and here is the result

[image]

The proper result should be:

19,13,9,1 instead of 1,13,19,9 see what i mean?

models.py

```
class empleado(models.Model):


    empresa = models.ForeignKey(empresa)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    fecha_nacimiento = models.DateField(auto_now_add=False)

    GENDER_CHOICES = (

        ('M', 'Masculino'),
        ('F', 'Femenino'),
    )

    sexo = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    avatar = StdImageField(upload_to='avatar/%Y/%m/%d', variations={
        'large': (300, 300, True),
        'medium': (50, 50, True),
        'thumbnail': (98, 122, True)})

    correo = models.EmailField(max_length=100)

    departamento = models.ForeignKey(departamento)

    telefono = models.CharField(max_length=21)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    usuario = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    primer_lugar = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    segundo_lugar = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    tercer_lugar = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    goleador = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    puntos = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=0)
    partidos = models.CharField(max_length=4, default=0)

    def avatarEmpleado(self):
        return '<img src="/media/%s" height="90" width="90">' % (self.avatar.thumbnail)

    avatarEmpleado.allow_tags = True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Comment: Could you please show us the definition of the `empleado` model?

Comment: i did a raw SQL Query on the MySQL console to MySQL and gives the same results so i think its not Django Query that is bad. because this Query gives the same results
SELECT
puntos, partidos
FROM
empresa_empleado
WHERE 
empresa_id =1
ORDER BY puntos DESC;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because puntos is a charfield so it's ordering lexicographically, so "9" > "19". If you want to order it numerically you need a integerfield or floatfield.

I would suggest to edit the model but if you can't [check out this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2969983/263989)

Comment: You are 100% right it is fixed. I've 12 hours without sleep before i added this 2 new fields :) thanks and i'm sorry for the obvious question

Comment: No problem @eddwinpaz , this things happen to me all the time :)

Comment: I have a similar issue but I am ordering by pk, is primary key a charfield to?

Comment: Depends on how do you defined your models @Manza, open a new question and I'll try to help you

Comment: @fasouto thank you I add in the model     class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id',)     and it worked thank you