# Use TO_CHAR in Django filter query method that makes a join

Tags: django

I need to cast a field via TO_CHAR using Django. I know I can:

```
Author.objects.extra(where=["TO_CHAR(name) = 'John'"])
```

and I also can:

```
Author.objects.filter(article__name='CoolArticle')
```

which will make the join on Article behind the scenes. Is there a way to combine both and achieve this:

```
author.articles.filter(website__name='AwesomeWeb')
# where website__name is casted via TO_CHAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a [custom transformer lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-lookups/#a-simple-transformer-example). Something like:

```
from django.db.models import Transform
from django.db.models.fields import Field

class ToChar(Transform):
    lookup_name = 'tochar'
    function = 'TO_CHAR'

Field.register_lookup(ToChar)
```

Now you should be able to do:

```
author.articles.filter(website__name__tochar='AwesomeWeb')
```

Comment: other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36274599/39296)