# Django - order_by() char and numerical

Tags: django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have to sort a list of objects containing hostnames.

The hostnames are in these formats: `h1, h5, h10, h12, h12-abc, h1000, x10`

If i use order_by('hostname') it will order like this:

```
h1, h10, h1000, h12, h12-abc, h5, x10
```

How would i achieve an ordering like this:

```
h1, h5, h10, h12, h12-abc, h1000, x10
```

The hostnames always begin with a char, then 1-4 digits and partly an extension, like for example '-abc'.

I guess i have to use Substr() to extract the number and order the numbers somehow, that '10' will not be listed before '5'.

With a search i found some old examples with extra() but the Django documentation says it will be deprecated in future and 'Use this method as a last resort'
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra

What is a future-proof way to do it?

Comment: Looks like these two answers should help you:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967500/how-to-correctly-sort-a-string-with-a-number-inside   and   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: @DanSwain i think the OP want to use the django orm

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: @BearBrown PostgreSQL

Comment: Have you looked at [db functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#substr)? I wrote down this idea, but I have no idea if it would work, but may be a starting point `Hosts.objects.annotate(
    letter=Substr("hostname", 0, 1),
    extension=StrIndex(F("hostname"), Value("-")),
).annotate(
    numerical=Cast(Substr("hostname", 1, Coalesce("extension", Value(None))), IntegerField()),
).order_by("extensions", "numerical")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the [f-expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions)

```
from django.db.models import F, Value, TextField, IntegerField
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
from django.db.models.expressions import Func

sql = ordModel.objects.annotate(
        num=Cast(
            Func(
                F('hostname'),
                Value("\d+"),
                function='regexp_matches',
            ),
            output_field=ArrayField(IntegerField())
        ),
        char=Func(
            F('hostname'),
            Value("\D+"),
            function='regexp_matches',
            output_field=ArrayField(TextField())
        )
    ).order_by('char', 'num', ).values('hostname')
```

my result for the same list of values is:

```
<QuerySet [
{'hostname': 'h1'},
{'hostname': 'h5'},
{'hostname': 'h10'},
{'hostname': 'h12'},
{'hostname': 'h12-abc'},
{'hostname': 'h1000'},
{'hostname': 'x10'}]>
```

about the database function you can readL [regexp_match](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP)

Comment: output looks great, but where is `function='regexp_matches'` coming from?

Comment: this is the postgres function https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: on a second view , the order is not really correct. it orders like order_by(hostname) , which i try to avoid. it should be h1, h5, h10, h12, h12-abc, h1000, x10 -  not h1, h10, h1000, h12 and so on - any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @FelixK i fixed the regexp now the result should be fine.

Comment: For PostgreSQL this works, so i will accept this as the answer. Below you will find my alternative database independent solution, which works too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work with an extra field `normalized_hostname`, which is also database independent. Implemented in the model with the help of Django Signals `pre_save()`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#pre-save

The code below transformes the hostname to a format, which then can be used with `order_by('normalized_hostname')`

> Examples:
>  hostname -> normalized_hostname

```
h1 -> h0001 
h5 -> h0005, 
h10 -> h0010 
h12 -> h0012
h12-abc -> h0012-abc 
h1000 -> h1000 
x10 -> x0010
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
import re

class MyModel(models.Model):
  the solution is also database independent  hostname = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    normalized_hostname = models.CharField(max_length=64)



def create_normalize_hostname(instance):
    normalize = re.sub("\D", "", instance.hostname).zfill(4)
    normalized_hostname = re.sub("(\d{1,4})", normalize, instance.hostname)
    return normalized_hostname

def receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs)
    instance.normalized_hostname = create_normalize_hostname(instance)

pre_save.connect(receiver, sender=ModelName)
```

Now it will order like this:

```
h1, h5, h10, h12, h12-abc, h1000, x10
```