# How can i convert string to int and then sort view by int value?

Tags: django, django-views

I want sort view by a value that is string. but before that, i want convert string to int then sort by that.

```
main = models.Main.objects.all().order_by('fore_key__n')
```

In this code `fore_key__n` is string value like '20'

Comment: You can use `ord()` and `chr()` to get the ASCII representation of a single charactor. So you can convert your string in a list of numbers, sort them and the convert back a string of characters.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969348/django-ordering-numerical-value-with-order-by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and [DB functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/) can probably do this. [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) the string value to an int and then use it to order the queryset. I haven't ever had cause to try this, so treat the following as a suggestion:

```
 main = models.Main.objects.annotate(
   fkn_int_cast=Cast('fore_key__n', output_field=IntegerField()),
 ).order_by('fkn_int_cast')
```

It will throw a `django.db.utils.DataError` should the data in the field not be capable of conversion. Therefore, it's probably necessary to apply a regex filter as well

```
 main = models.Main.objects.filter(
   fore_key_n__regex='^[0-9]+$'
 ).annotate(
   fkn_int_cast=Cast('fore_key__n', output_field=IntegerField()),
 ).order_by('fkn_int_cast')
```

There are other DB functions you might use, for example, to replace the commas in '1,234,456' with null strings so it becomes Cast'able